# Odoo - Add Outstanding payment to invoice through API

Tags: odoo, odoo-15

Using Odoo 15 and python xmlrpc for API

here is my problem: I have a created payment for which I store the id. Then, when i create the invoice that corresponds, I want to be able to add this specific outstanding credit of the customer through API just like this "Ajouter" (Add) button  does. ("crédits en circulation" is outstanding credits):

[invoice screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NzsZ2.png)

How would I do with python and xml-rpc tu simulate the use of this button for a specific payment (with its id)?

Note: For our sales workflow we have to create payments straight away and invoices later so I can't create the payment when creating the invoice

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you click on `Add` button, Odoo will call the [js_assign_outstanding_line](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/dd64fc7730ef34d715cfb2146a7ef8a7ba98f34e/addons/account/static/src/js/account_payment_field.js#L121-L133) function.

```
def js_assign_outstanding_line(self, line_id):
    ''' Called by the 'payment' widget to reconcile a suggested journal item to the present
    invoice.
    :param line_id: The id of the line to reconcile with the current invoice.
    '''
    self.ensure_one()
    lines = self.env['account.move.line'].browse(line_id)
    lines += self.line_ids.filtered(lambda line: line.account_id == lines[0].account_id and not line.reconciled)
    return lines.reconcile()
```

The `Add` button depends on the value of the computed [invoice_outstanding_credits_debits_widget](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/dd64fc7730ef34d715cfb2146a7ef8a7ba98f34e/addons/account/models/account_move.py#L328) field. To reproduce the same logic using XML-RPC, you need to get the payment credit line id and call the `js_assign_outstanding_line` function like following:

```
models.execute_kw(db, uid, password, 'account.move', 'js_assign_outstanding_line', [move_id, line_id])
```

It will add the payment and return the result of `reconcile` function which will raise the following error (XML-RPC code):

```
TypeError: cannot marshal <class \'odoo.api.account.partial.reconcile\'> objects\n'>
```